# Mule ESB vm arguments are ignored

Tags: jvm, mule, jvm-arguments, mule-esb

I am trying for couple of hours now and it seem I cannot find a solution, how to set vm arguments when mule standalone is started.

There are many sources that are saying I could set arguments in wrapper.conf like so: `wrapper.java.additional.21=-Djavax.net.debug=all` or when starting mule through command line like so: `./mule -M-Djavax.net.debug=all` but nothing is working.

I made no changes to mule file or any other that I think matters.

What am I doing wrong?

ESB standalone version: 3.7 CE

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if you set parameter in wrapper and when starting mule then somehow setting is ignored. Make sure you use it only at one place.